# If I have Greek Visa, can I use it to visit other Schengen countries after my arrival in Greece

Tags: visas, schengen, greece

I am planning to travel to Greece so I want to know if I can visit other Schengen countries with the visa and also by train from Greece after my arrival in Greece

Comment: Surely you mean Schengen countries, not Shanghai countries.

Comment: Would this be visiting other Schengen countries on the same trip, or do you have a multiple-entry visa and you're thinking about coming back another time?

Comment: What type of visa do you have (a Schengen visa or a long-stay visa like a student or work visa)?

Comment: There is no way this question can be considered a duplicate. We don't even know if the answer really applies. It should have been closed as “unclear” and could still be reopened if the OP provides more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can as Greece is a part of Schengen zone.

I assume you are worried because of the current situation in Greece, of course you can never be 100% sure about political stuff, but no matter what happens they gonna stay in a Schengen zone for quite some time.

So if you are travelling anytime soon, you should be good.

Comment: A correct answer! But given the current situation, will it always be?  Can you please add more substance to upgrade the quality of this answer?

Comment: @GayotFow Even in the event of Grexit they still are not leaving Schengen

Comment: @Karlson, good to know, but he still needs to think up a way to upgrade the quality of his answer

Comment: @GayotFow No doubt even if it is a duplicate...

Comment: updated the answer